# Edit existing data in SQL Server database

Tags: c#

I have a table `SupplierMaster` in a SQL Server database with a column `SUPPLIERNAME`.

I want to edit saved supplier name using stored procedure with below query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SupplierMasterUpdateDetails]
(
    @SUPPLIERNAME NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[SupplierMaster]
    SET [SUPPLIERNAME] = @SUPPLIERNAME
    WHERE [SUPPLIERNAME] = @SUPPLIERNAME
END
```

and I run the BELOW code through "UPDATE BUTTON"  to update the data.

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_SupplierMasterUpdateDetails", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // Parameter
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SUPPLIERNAME", AddSupplierTextBox.Text);

        // Open Connection
        conn.Open();

        // ExecuteReader (Select Statement)
        // ExecuteScalar (Select Statement)
        // ExecuteNonQuery (Insert, Update or Delete)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED", "Successful", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

But its not updating the selected data.

Please advice and assist me to correct the code for proper work.

Comment: any errormessage?

Comment: no......no code is running when pressing the update button and msg also showing that updated sucessfully but in data base data is remain same there is no changes

Comment: Your stored procedure doesn't make sense... it sets the supplier name to `@SUPPLIERNAME` on rows that already have that name, so it will never change anything. You should select the row to update based on the primary key, not the current name.

Comment: Yes.....Sorry its was due to wrong stored procedure.........now its working......Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues there.

First you need to fix your update query just as Thomas Levesque suggested.
a SQL Server table needs a primary key to be able to uniquely identify a record, for updates for example.

The easiest thing you could do is set that primary key to be identity of type int and make it self generating. Your supplier table could look like this :

```
SupplierID int, Primary Key, identity
SupplierName nvarchar(100)
```

Now, when you do an update, you would do it like this:

```
Update SupplierMaster
Set SupplierName = @supplierName
Where SupplierID = @suplierID
```

Such a SQL statement will return an int value. This return value will tell you how many SQL rows this update statement has changed. If it says 0 then it means that the SQL statement could not find that id you passed through and nothing changed. If it says 1, then the record was found and updated, if you get more than 1 you have an issue with the SQL statement and multiple rows were updated.

In your code check for this return value and that's how you determine if your update statement was successful or not.